# IsInitialized not working with NHibernate LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lazy-loading, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to figure out if a lazy collection has been loaded or not so I know whether to include it in the DTO. Below is my code.

**Controller**

```
IEnumerable<Store> stores = StoreService.GetList(new int[] { 1, 2}, true);

StoreDTO tStore = StoreService.GetDTO(stores.First());
```

**StoreService**

```
public IEnumerable<Store> GetList(int[] Ids, bool stockItems = false)
    {
        IQueryable<Store> stores =  StoreRepository.GetList(Ids);

        if (stockItems)
            stores.Fetch(s => s.StockItems);

        return stores.ToList();
    }

public StoreDTO GetDTO(Store store)
    {
        StoreDTO storeDTO = Mapper.Map<Store, StoreDTO>(store);

        bool itemsFetched = NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(store.StockItems);

        if(itemsFetched) { /** do stuff **/ }

        return storeDTO;
    }
```

Problem is itemsFetched is always false but if I put a break point on it and then use the VS debugger to look at the StockItems and then let the break point through it returns true.

Does this mean that the NHibernate LINQ provider is broken or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for `StoreRepository.GetList()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that IsInitialized() returns false because you haven't applied the fetch to the IQueryable that you are actually executing. Try:

```
if (stockItems)
    stores = stores.Fetch(s => s.StockItems);
```

During/after debugging, IsInitialized() returns true because the debugger itself will trigger the lazy load of the collection when you explore the object.